# Make gameObject child of the gameObject which is at the position of the button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's hard to explain my question. I have 16 tiles with 9 buttons between them:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/7f0402427b37fdba8a267b7a9ca9dc68.png]

Behind every button is a white gameObject which is in the center of 4 tiles. If you press a button, the 4 tiles should rotate around the white gameObject. 
I thought that the best way to do this is that when you click a button, the 4 tiles around that button should become child of the white gameObject behind that button, so they can rotate with 4. 
How do I make it so, that when you press a button, the tiles around that button will become child of the white gameObject behind that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this but it can more or less be broken down into the few steps that you mentioned. This method assumes you have one script that you attach to each of the white objects.

You first need to generate a list of objects that the white object is touching. This could either be done using OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter or by performing a distance check. Below is an example of how OnTriggerEnter could be used after tagging each of the colored squares. Then you can simply loop through the 4 objects in the list and assign their parent to the white square:

```
void SquareClicked()
{
    foreach(GameObject square in NeighborList)
    {
        square.transform.parent = gameObject.Transform;
    }
    DoRotate(); //this is where you do the rotation of the parent object.
}

List<GameObject> NeighborList = new List<GameObject>();
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "coloredsquare") //tag each square with this tag.
    {
         NeighborList.Add(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'm doing something wrong cause nothing happends. 

- Am I supposed to add the void SquareClicked() to a button? (I tested it by putting the function in Start())
- The white gameobjects have a box collider with is trigger selected, the squares have a box collider without is trigger
- I added this script to all the white gameobjects
- I added tags.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes there is more to it than just this code. You will call SquareClicked from whatever method you are using to detect a click on the game object. If there is a button component attached to this white square you can call this function using the [onClick listener](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) for buttons.

Comment: But the complicated thing is that the button component isn't on the white gameobject, but on the button in front of it.

Comment: is the white object a child of the button? you will need some sort of relation you can navigate through.

Comment: At the moment, the sqaures and the white gameobjects are both child of the same parent, so that is has the same scales etc. The buttons are child of another parent.

Comment: I think I got it to work. In your code, transform.parent should be gameObject.transform.

Comment: Good catch. Glad to hear it!